# How to match with smaller than operator in flex?

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am trying to match the strings in a file with the regular expressions in flex. For example, to match with assignment operator, I write:

```
= printf("tASSIGN token");
```

But when I want to match with the operator `<`, it doesn't accept the following line:

```
< printf("tLT token");
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<` character is special to lex -- it is used to mark a pattern as only applying in certain states.  To get a literal `<` you need to escape or quote it:

```
"<"    printf("tLT token");
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried [<] and it also worked. Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: @bigO:  No, nothing wrong -- you can use `""` or `[]` around a single character with the same net effect.  Or `\\` before it.